# Auto execute when input changes

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I just started learning PHP and I want to make a simple plugin for WordPress. I have written this and set it to calculate `$resultado` on submit. This is working fine but now I want that `$result` to auto-calculate everytime I change an input value so I can see the result everytime and not to have to press the button.

Is this possible with JavaScript?

```
function formulario_webbudget(){
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  Nombre: <input type="text" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['nombre']); ?>" name="nombre" required><br>
  Apellido: <input type="text" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['apellido']); ?>" name="apellido" required><br>
  Correo: <input type="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['correo']); ?>" name="correo" required><br>
  <hr>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" <?php if(isset($_POST['check'])) { echo "checked"; }?>> SEO check<br>

  Dominio
  <select name="dominio">
    <option>No</option>
    <option <?php if ($_POST['dominio'] == 'si') { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="si">Si (20€)</option>
  </select><br> 

  Hosting
  <select name="hosting">
    <option>No</option>
    <option <?php if ($_POST['hosting'] == 'si') { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="si">Si (50€)</option>
  </select><br> 

  Diseño adaptado patatin patatan
  <select name="diseno">
    <option>No</option>
    <option <?php if ($_POST['diseno'] == 'si') { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="si">Si (200€)</option>
  </select><br> 

  Posisionamiento SEO patatin patatan
  <select name="seo">
    <option>No</option>
    <option <?php if ($_POST['seo'] == 'si') { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="si">Si (100€)</option>
  </select><br>

  Numero de paginas extra patatin patatan
  <input type="number" name="paginas"><br>

  Observaciones:    
  <textarea name="observaciones" maxlength="500" placeholder="Escriba sus observaciones">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['observaciones'])) { 
      echo htmlentities ($_POST['observaciones']); 
    }
    ?>
  </textarea>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Calcular"></p> 
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['check'])) {
    $valor6 = '70';
}

if ($_POST['dominio'] == 'si'){
    $valor1 = '20';
    $dominio = 'dominio blablabla';
}
if ($_POST['hosting'] == 'si'){
    $valor2 = '50';
    $hosting = 'hosting blablabla';
}

if ($_POST['seo'] == 'si'){
    $valor3 = '100';
    $seo = 'seo blablabla';
}
if ($_POST['diseno'] == 'si'){
    $valor4 = '200';
    $diseno = 'diseno blablabla';
}

$valor5 = $_POST['paginas'] * '50';

$resultado = $valor1 + $valor2 + $valor3 + $valor4 + $valor5 + $valor6;
echo 'El presupuesto base para su web sería de ' , $resultado , '€';
?> 

<?php
}
add_shortcode('webbudget', 'formulario_webbudget');
?>
```

Comment: yes, it's possible with javascript.

Comment: Try looking at this page: [jQuery Submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).